# Convert normal human readable datetime to unix timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have created an SQL model in snowflake that gives a several outputs among those ones, I have two columns that are the next :

- The first column: called `last_used` that gives a human readable datetime in the next format `2023-12-01 20:24`
- The second column called `date` that gives a human readable date in the next format : `2023-12-01`

Is there any functionality in snowflake that converts those two columns into unix timestamp which will do the contrary of `to_timestamp()` ?

In a second hand, is there any possibility that unix timestamp in snowflake will be aware of timezone ?

Thank you in advance ! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the documentation for [Date & Time Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time#supported-date-and-time-parts) you want to use `epoch_second` and DATE_PART:

```
select 
    '2023-12-01 20:24'::timestamp as col_a
    ,'2023-12-01'::date as col_b
    ,date_part('epoch_second', col_a) as epoch_a
    ,date_part('epoch_second', col_b) as epoch_b
;
```

gives:

[image]

Unix timestamps do not in of themselves have a time zone, which is why in my past jobs the servers mostly use GMT to avoid timezone daylight savings changes messing with logs twice a year. But like all timestamps, you can convert from one timezone to another, via the [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone), I would just be explicit about the source/destination timezones, otherwise you will get the Snowflake servers, which are not GTM...